# iOS how to find country code of the user's phone number?

Tags: ios, telephony

I have an app that needs to figure out the country code of the phone number the user has. My understanding is that I can't just get the phone number of the user, but, is there a way for example if I have a US phone number to get the country code +1?

I have found multiple answers that claim that using core telephony you can get the country code "+1" but I tried a few and none of them work.

I tried this:

```
CTTelephonyNetworkInfo *network_Info = [CTTelephonyNetworkInfo new];
CTCarrier *carrier = network_Info.subscriberCellularProvider;
NSString *mnc = [carrier mobileNetworkCode];
NSString *mcc = [carrier mobileCountryCode];    
NSLog(@"country code is: %@, mnc: %@, mcc: %@", carrier.mobileCountryCode, mnc, mcc);
```

which prints:

```
"country code is: 310, mnc: 410, mcc: 310"
```

So, for a US number I would like to get +1.

Is there a way to do this?

EDIT:
With further search I found this:

[How to map MCC + MNC to users phone country code in iOS objective-C without using Location info?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25070897/how-to-map-mcc-mnc-to-users-phone-country-code-in-ios-objective-c-without-usin)

It might do the trick, but I was looking for a more official way to do this.

Comment: There is no API for this. Find a database, include it in app and look up this information there.

Comment: Easier said than done: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_country_calling_codes

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can get the country code with:

```
NSString *cc = [carrier isoCountryCode];
```

Which will give you `US` for a USA based device. You can map from country code to country phone code via the JSON data available on [this](http://country.io/data/).

Comment: This works. NOTE: it won't work on the simulator since it does not run on a specific "carrier" thus carrier will be nil and won't be able to return isoCountryCode. Nice API!