# Swift 2 country code for a phone number

Tags: ios, swift, swift2

I am trying to get the country code from iPhone user. I am not sure is there any information about the country and how some applications (like Viber) suggest dial code.

I got this far:

```
    let currentLocale = NSLocale.currentLocale()
    let a = currentLocale.localeIdentifier
```

I tested this on simulator and it returns "en_US". Can someone advice how should I get dial code for a country based on this (or at least country code, which I will send to server to get dial code).

Thanks!

Comment: It seems you have to get the country's ISO code, and look up the dial code from that. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25095778/ios-how-to-find-country-code-of-the-users-phone-number

Comment: Thanks! I will add answer based on that question. Since they answered for objective C

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Based on suggestion from Pekka, this is how country identifier can be loaded:

```
   // Setup the Network Info and create a CTCarrier object
   let networkInfo = CTTelephonyNetworkInfo()
   let carrier = networkInfo.subscriberCellularProvider

   // Get carrier name
   let countryCode = carrier?.isoCountryCode
   return countryCode
```

Also, it is important to import `CoreTelephony` class

```
import CoreTelephony
```

After that dial code for a country can be get from http://country.io/data/

Also be aware that this will not work on iOS simulator, since it doesn't provide carrier.

Comment: That's an awesome solution!!

Comment: Don't forget to run this code in the main tread if not - you get a crash.